# Client X.509 certificate

Tags: spring, security, certificate, x509certificate, sign

I need to encypt a document using client's public key. I can get the client certificate from their website. My question is how my application should access this certificate?

- Should I get it from their website each time it is required?
- Or, should I download it and store it:

  - in my KeyStore
  - Or, just as a file locally

I also need to validate this certificate and use CRL.
My application uses latest Spring versions.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a private key for signing.

Comment: Updated the ques. It is required for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the certificate each time (if it is available). But you also need to validate the certificate each time and do a full chain validation [Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) (on Page 71, Chapter 6: Certification Path Validation) including CRL and/or OCSP.

If you do not download the certificate, how would you know that it has changed? Certificates do not only change if they are expired.

Use a hybrid encryption scheme for the document encryption.

**Update:**

> Can you please tell what do you mean by "Certificates do not only change if they are expired."? What else can change and how does it matter?

I mean that you need to check the certificate every time you access that service. A quick and dirty solution would be to download the certificate  once, look for the expiration date and only re-check the certificate if the expiration date has passed. But that would be devastating to the public key infrastructure system. The idea is to check the certificate every time you access some service. Certificates may change before their expiration date and that may have it's reason.

See in the provided link [RFC 5280 on page 69](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) for some reasons:

```
CRLReason ::= ENUMERATED {
    unspecified             (0),
    keyCompromise           (1),
    cACompromise            (2),
    affiliationChanged      (3),
    superseded              (4),
    cessationOfOperation    (5),
    certificateHold         (6),
         -- value 7 is not used
    removeFromCRL           (8),
    privilegeWithdrawn      (9),
    aACompromise           (10) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide a link to how to do this? validation and full chani validation?

Comment: Added a link to the RFC

Comment: Can you please tell what do you mean by "Certificates do not only change if they are expired."? What else can change and how does it matter?